# Quantifier follows nothing in regex

Tags: perl, grep

My requirement is to print the files having **'xyz'** text in their file names using **perl**.
I tried below and got the following error

**Quantifier follows nothing in regex  marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE xyz.xlsx$/;**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw(file_xyz.xlsx,file.xlsx);
my @my_files = grep { /*xyz.xlsx$/ } @files;
for my $file (@my_files) {
    print "The output $file \n";
}
```

Problem is coming when I add `*` in grep regular expression. 
How can I possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `*` is a meta character, called a quantifier. It means "repeat the previous character or character class zero or more times". In your case, it follows nothing, and is therefore a syntax error. What you probably are trying is to match anything, which is `.*`: Wildcard, followed by a quantifier. However, this is already the default behaviour of a regex match unless it is anchored. So all you need is:

```
my @my_files = grep { /xyz/ } @files;
```

You could keep your end of the string anchor `xlsx$`, but since you have a limited list of file names, that hardly seems necessary. Though you have used `qw()` wrong, it is not comma separated, it is space separated:

```
my @files = qw(file_xyz.xlsx file.xlsx);
```

However, if you should have a larger set of file names, such as one read from a directory, you can place a wildcard string in the middle:

```
my @my_files = grep { /xyz.*\.xlsx$/i } @files;
```

Note the use of the `/i` modifier to match case insensitively. Also note that you must escape `.` because it is another meta character.

Comment: Yes exactly. I have added '*' to match any characters and it should have 'xyz' and ending with '.xlsx' .. Then how can I achieve my requirement

Comment: yes yeah got it. I made a mistake by adding comma in qw().. Thanks for you answer..

Comment: @Mari You're welcome. Usually, Perl gives you a warning when you mis-use `qw()`.

Comment: Thanks bro :) You have added many possible ways of not missing our search text... very well..

Comment: @Mari Well, you know, in Perl there's more than one way to do it. ;)

Comment: Yeah. Started learning Perl. Was a big fan of Bash scripting and now more into Perl for it's wide features!!